# How do I add another ACF option to my elseif statement?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to add another banner image to my Wordpress ACF options for page.php. I would like to do this so I can create a default banner image for the default Wordpress template. I am not sure how to do it.

```
<?php if (is_page_template('template-projects.php')) { ?>

    <?php
     $banimage2 = get_field('banner_img', 'options'); // Array returned by Advanced Custom Fields
     $banimage2Alt = $banimage2['alt']; // Grab, from the array, the 'alt'
     $banimage2Width = $banimage2['width']; // Grab, from the array, the 'width'
     $banimage2Height = $banimage2['height']; // Grab, from the array, the 'height'
     $banimage2ThumbURL = $banimage2['sizes']['large']; //grab from the array, the 'sizes', and from it, the 'thumbnail'
    ?>

    <img class="box-banner" src="<?php echo $banimage2ThumbURL;?>"  alt="<?php echo $banimage2Alt; ?>"  width="<?php echo $banimage2Width; ?>" height="<?php echo $banimage2Height; ?>" />

<?php } elseif (is_singular('projects')) { ?>

    <?php
     $banimage3 = get_field('pd_banner', $post_id); // Array returned by Advanced Custom Fields
     $banimage3Alt = $banimage3['alt']; // Grab, from the array, the 'alt'
     $banimage3Width = $banimage3['width']; // Grab, from the array, the 'width'
     $banimage3Height = $banimage3['height']; // Grab, from the array, the 'height'
     $banimage3ThumbURL = $banimage3['sizes']['large']; //grab from the array, the 'sizes', and from it, the 'thumbnail'
    ?>

    <img class="box-banner" src="<?php echo $banimage3ThumbURL;?>"  alt="<?php echo $banimage3Alt; ?>"  width="<?php echo $banimage3Width; ?>" height="<?php echo $banimage3Height; ?>" />

<?php } else { ?>
    <?php
     $banimage = get_field('banner_img'); // Array returned by Advanced Custom Fields
     $banimageAlt = $banimage['alt']; // Grab, from the array, the 'alt'
     $banimageWidth = $banimage['width']; // Grab, from the array, the 'width'
     $banimageHeight = $banimage['height']; // Grab, from the array, the 'height'
     $banimageThumbURL = $banimage['sizes']['large']; //grab from the array, the 'sizes', and from it, the 'thumbnail'
    ?>
    <?php if(get_field('banner_img')): ?>
    <img class="box-banner" src="<?php echo $banimageThumbURL;?>"  alt="<?php echo $banimageAlt; ?>"  width="<?php echo $banimageWidth; ?>"  height="<?php echo $banimageHeight; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer was to add an additional ELSE at the bottom of the statement.

```
<?php else: ?>
    <img class="box-banner" src="<?php the_field('banner_img', 'options' ); ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got totally what you want to do, but to add a new condition in your `if` `else` statement, you can add it like this:

```
[...]

<?php elseif (is_singular('projects')) : ?>

   [...]

<?php elseif ( [YOUR CONDITION] ) : ?>

   [DO YOUR THING]

<?php else : ?>

   [...]

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think I might need to <?php elseif ( is_page_template('page.php') ) : ?> I'll tinker with it and see.  Thanks for the help, I'll follow up.